# Communicate With Multiple Devices Using One IP

Tags: networking, network-interface, bridge

I am working on a project where I have to communicate with multiple devices (same manufacturer, same model) from my Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) computer. For simplicity, I will stick to two devices, named A and B, with static IPs [192.168.0.A] and [192.168.0.B]. The Linux computer (Called the **H**ost) has multiple NIC, each with multiple ethernet ports. Again, for simplicity, I will stick with two NICs (NIC.x, NIC.y) with three ethernet ports each. A port will have the IP "192.168.0.x**N**", where N can be 1, 2, or 3.

To communicate with the devices I have to use the SDK provided by the device manufacturer, in which I have to specify the host IP, and the device IP I wish to communicate with. The problem is, to communicate with multiple devices at the same time I have to provide one host IP, and the IPs of the devices you want to communicate with. This works when you have an external switch, in which all the devices are connected to it. In my case, I wish to connect the devices to my Host NICs, but by doing so each device will have a different "Host IP", and the SDK won't allow that.

The solution that I arrived to, is to create a bridge using "ip link" for NIC.y, adding all three ports to the bridge. I then connected the devices to NIC.y2 and NIC.y3, connected NIC.y1 to NIC.x3, and set NIC.x3 to a static IP. I have attached a picture below to clarity.

[image]

My question is, is there a better way to do this, without the need of adding an external switch? Mainly I would like to get rid of the cable connecting NIC.y1 and NIC.x3.

In summary:
I need to end up with list of devices with static IPs (192.168.0.A , 192.168.0.B, .....) with all reachable from a single host static IP (192.168.0.H) even though they are physically connected over different ports/NICs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux has what is called virtual *bridge* devices, which you can use to make a network consisting of multiple physical and virtual Ethernet interfaces. In your case, you'd set up a bridge with the two y ports and a virtual interface with a static IP address attached to it.

Comment: That did the trick, cheers!